# Cabecera dinámica de una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con `Codeigniter`(*PHP*), y *Mysql* y quisiera hacer que la cabecera de mi tabla el `thead` sea dinámico que a partir de los datos que me arroje una consulta los ponga en el encabezado.

**Ejemplo:** Si mi consulta me trae Guadalajara, México, Durango, etc. en mi tabla se muestre:

```
<table id="venta">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Gudalajara</th>
        <th>México</th>
        <th>Durango</th>
        <th>Tonelas</th>
        <th>etc</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

y así dependiendo que valores me traiga mi consulta. 
y ya posterior mente llenar el `body` de la tabla.
Utilizo *JSON, javaScript, codeigniter, bootstraptable, html5.*

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar? Gracias,

**Recuperar datos:**

```
$('#lugar').bootstrapTable({
      url:'<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/ejemplo1/ejemplo/datos',
      columns: [
        {field: 'status'},
        {field: 'personas'},
        {field: 'estado'}, 
      ],

      pagination: true,
      showFooter: true,
      search: true,
      showExport:true,
      filter: true,
      method: 'post',
      showRefresh:true
    });
```

Aquí lo que quiero es que el campo de estado sea la cabecera de mi tabla y ya de ahí acomodar su valor correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Y con que lenguaje te conectas a la bd? ¿y como estas trayendo los resultados? ¿y cual es tu código para recuperar los datos? O más importante aún ¿que problema exacto tienes?

Comment: listo @Xerif, eso es el código que utilizo

Answer (score 1):

Haz una consulta adicional, usando los mismos filtros:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ciudad FROM tabla WHERE --Mismo filtro que utilizas para extraer los datos-- ORDER BY ciudad
```

Solo agrega otra propiedad 'ciudades' al JSON para crear los encabezados; el único posible inconveniente es que en los resultados haya una o más filas que no llenen todas las columnas.

Comment: Gracias @Triby, ya lo solucione.